# can anyone explain me the orders of variable given below?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 int x=5;
 char A_one[8], A_two[8];
}
```

I think x will be at higher address then A_two and A_one(decreasing).

Comment: Why don't you try it and see for yourself?

Comment: No, just no. If the address of these is not taken in the program they a) may be completely elided, or, b) stored in registers instead, c) the layout of such variables in memory is implementation-defined anyhow.

Comment: I tried sir but I got lower address for x . And I am reading a book , in that the address of x is highest. @ErikW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not defined, so it cannot be answered in general.

For any specific case you can easily try it by printing out the addresses:

```
printf("x is at %p, A_two at %p and A_one at %p\n", (void *) &x,
       (void *) &A_two, (void *) &A_one);
```

Note that the C standard does not, for instance, require that these variables are put on a stack.

Comment: But I have read that the growth of stack from higher address to lower address, so x should go first at higher address. @unwind

Comment: @pushpamk That might be true for some particular compiler and OS, but you didn't specify such details. C doesn't specify any of that, it's up to the implementation.